# Nebular with Angular, how to get the value of @Output from a component in a window

Tags: angular9, nebular

I have opened a component in NbWindow. I want to close it when the window component emits data. the control of opening and closing it should remain with the parent component from where it was called.

Example:

- Parent calls window (with child component)
- I fill the form in the child component and emit the data
- Once the parent receives it, it closes the window

How to achieve this?